# PHPMailer not working on Web Hosting

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have been able to send emails using xampp, but when I tried to use it in my online server it doesn't seem to work. I tried changing the values on what was written on my email account information. It doesn't seem work, I was hoping for any guidance or help for anyone who has encountered this problem.

This is the email account details

[image: Email Account Details]

then this is my code for my mailer.php

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {

  $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

  $mail->isSMTP();
  $mail->Host = 'localhost';
  $mail->Username = 'email';
  $mail->Password = 'password';

  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->Port = 465;

  $mail->setFrom('email', 'Test Message');

  $mail->addAddress("email");

  $mail->isHTML(true);
  $mail->Subject = 'This is the Subject';
  $mail->Body    = 'This has been sent';
  $mail->AltBody = 'This has been sent';

  $mail->send();
  echo 'Message has been sent';

 } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: <br>', $mail->ErrorInfo;
 }
```

I get the error **SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)
SMTP connect() failed.**

I am still kinda new to this, so sorry in advance for anything. I feel I am soo close to getting it work haha!

Thanks in advance for any help! :D

Comment: The value of `$mail->Host = 'localhost';` should be set to the value shown in the `Server` field of the image you posted.

Comment: @Dave I tried it just now sir, any unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. Though it worked when I was using localhost and then i removed this sir `$mail->isSMTP();. Though I know it will then use the built in mail function. So I don't really know haha

Comment: Did the error message change when you used the name or IP of the server?

Comment: @Dave It's still the same problem sir, but I tried changing the port number to 25 and removing the `SMTPSecure` it gives me a problem of _Could not connect to SMTP Host_ haha

Comment: What does the debug trace show? Changing it to port 25 will not work. Could not connect is a different error than connection refused which is what your post said you were getting.

Comment: Try using `isSMTP()` with `SMTPSecure = false`. SSL to localhost will always fail because the certificate will not match.

Answer (score 0):

it's so simple... Use this code:

```
<?php
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
    require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
    require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $name = 'Name to be displayed!';
    $message = 'Never Give Up!';
    $subject = 'Test mail!';
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'yourmail@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = 'youpass';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->addReplyTo($to, $name);
    $mail->setFrom($to, $name);
    $mail->addAddress($to);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->msgHtml($message);
    $mail->send();
?>
```

Hope you added PHPMailer Library in Root Directory if not then please check the path also